# Data in Microsoft Dynamics NAV

Tags: dynamics-nav

How is data in Microsoft Dynamics NAV stored? Can I retrieve/send data from/to NAV from other systems?

Can I choose the database engine to use in NAV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How is data in Microsoft Dynamics NAV stored?

The way the data is stored is stored is version dependant.

- NAV 2009 or earlier: Administrators could choose a native database server or Microsoft SQL Server.
- NAV 2013 or later: Microsoft SQL Server only.

#### Can I retrieve/send data from/to NAV from other systems?

The way data is imported/exported is also version dependent.

- NAV 2013 or earlier: via backing up and restoring databases.
- NAV 2015: via Export-NAVData and Import-NAVData Windows PowerShell cmdlets.

---

> Before NAV 2013, Microsoft Dynamics NAV gave administrators the option of using either a native database server or Microsoft SQL Server, as the DBMS. SQL Server is now the exclusive database option for NAV. Retiring the old "Native database" has given way to long awaited improvements in reducing/eliminating database locking, which can occur when hundreds or thousands of users are using the same data at once.

Source [Microsoft Dynamics NAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_NAV)

---

> You can export a company from a Microsoft Dynamics NAV database and import it into another database, and you can export and import other types of data such as global data, application data, and application objects.
>
> In earlier versions of Microsoft Dynamics NAV, you exported and imported this type of data as part of backing up and restoring databases. In Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2015, you can do this by using the Export-NAVData and Import-NAVData Windows PowerShell cmdlets. You can also import and export data in the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Windows client and the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web client.

Source [Exporting and Importing Companies and Other Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn789595%28v=nav.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions, the data is stored in an SQL Server Database.
There is no other Database such as MySQL that you can use.

Regards
Peter